# How to choose negative samples? (OpenCV, Object Detection)

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I want to make a face detection application that detect only my face using Python, OpenCV. I wonder if there is any rule about choosing negative samples. Should I select the any image that does not contain my face? (For example: roads, scenes, animals etc.) or should I select faces of people that does not contain my face as negative image.

And also I wonder that does common environment where the object that looked for occupy affect the efficiency? (For example: Is it a good practice to select empty roads as negative image when detecting cars?)

I really wonder your thoughts. Could you also share articles, document about it if there is any? I would really appreciate for that. Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a difficult question, and depends heavily on your chosen algorithm. If you e.g. use SIFT, then you only use positive samples. If you are using Cascades then negative samples are necessary.

What samples to use depends on the application and no single answer exist. You should generally provide positive and negative samples covering the possible situations you could expect to appear. As the algorithm becomes even more complex (Deep Learning) this becomes even more relevant.

So if you think other faces can appear in the image and you want to make sure it sees them as negative you need to provide this. If your face can appear with different backgrounds then it is also important to include such situations.

To summarize, include samples (positive/negative) of situations expected to appear.